# Removing days and hours from a countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm using a countdown timer from this jQuery file but I want to remove the days and hours from it so it only shows minutes and seconds. Can anyone help me out? The digits are displayed from a png file which creates a flip board effect as it displays the countdown.

```js
jQuery.fn.countdown = function(userOptions)
{
  // Default options
  var options = {
    stepTime: 60,
    // startTime and format MUST follow the same format.
    // also you cannot specify a format unordered (e.g. hh:ss:mm is wrong)
    format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
    startTime: "01:12:32:55",
    digitImages: 6,
    digitWidth: 53,
    digitHeight: 77,
    timerEnd: function(){},
    image: "digits.png"
  };
  var digits = [], interval;

  // Draw digits in given container
  var createDigits = function(where) 
  {
    var c = 0;
    // Iterate each startTime digit, if it is not a digit
    // we'll asume that it's a separator
    for (var i = 0; i < options.startTime.length; i++)
    {
      if (parseInt(options.startTime[i]) >= 0) 
      {
        elem = $('<div id="cnt_' + i + '" class="cntDigit" />').css({
          height: options.digitHeight * options.digitImages * 10, 
          float: 'left', background: 'url(\'' + options.image + '\')',
          width: options.digitWidth});
        digits.push(elem);
        margin(c, -((parseInt(options.startTime[i]) * options.digitHeight *
                              options.digitImages)));
        digits[c].__max = 9;
        // Add max digits, for example, first digit of minutes (mm) has 
        // a max of 5. Conditional max is used when the left digit has reach
        // the max. For example second "hours" digit has a conditional max of 4 
        switch (options.format[i]) {
          case 'h':
            digits[c].__max = (c % 2 == 0) ? 2: 9;
            if (c % 2 == 0)
              digits[c].__condmax = 4;
            break;
          case 'd': 
            digits[c].__max = 9;
            break;
          case 'm':
          case 's':
            digits[c].__max = (c % 2 == 0) ? 5: 9;
        }
        ++c;
      }
      else 
        elem = $('<div class="cntSeparator"/>').css({float: 'left'})
                .text(options.startTime[i]);

      where.append(elem)
    }
  };
  
  // Set or get element margin
  var margin = function(elem, val) 
  {
    if (val !== undefined)
      return digits[elem].css({'marginTop': val + 'px'});

    return parseInt(digits[elem].css('marginTop').replace('px', ''));
  };

  // Makes the movement. This is done by "digitImages" steps.
  var moveStep = function(elem) 
  {
    digits[elem]._digitInitial = -(digits[elem].__max * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages);
    return function _move() {
      mtop = margin(elem) + options.digitHeight;
      if (mtop == options.digitHeight) {
        margin(elem, digits[elem]._digitInitial);
        if (elem > 0) moveStep(elem - 1)();
        else 
        {
          clearInterval(interval);
          for (var i=0; i < digits.length; i++) margin(i, 0);
          options.timerEnd();
          return;
        }
        if ((elem > 0) && (digits[elem].__condmax !== undefined) && 
            (digits[elem - 1]._digitInitial == margin(elem - 1)))
          margin(elem, -(digits[elem].__condmax * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages));
        return;
      }

      margin(elem, mtop);
      if (margin(elem) / options.digitHeight % options.digitImages != 0)
        setTimeout(_move, options.stepTime);

      if (mtop == 0) digits[elem].__ismax = true;
    }
  };

  $.extend(options, userOptions);
  this.css({height: options.digitHeight, overflow: 'hidden'});
  createDigits(this);
  interval = setInterval(moveStep(digits.length - 1), 1000);
};
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Countdown that doesn't sucks</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#counter').countdown({
          image: 'img/digits.png',
          startTime: '00:00:05:00'
        });

      });
    </script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
      br { clear: both; }
      .cntSeparator {
        font-size: 54px;
        margin: 10px 7px;
        color: #000;
      }
      .desc { margin: 7px 3px; }
      .desc div {
        float: left;
        font-family: Arial;
        width: 70px;
        margin-right: 65px;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
```

Comment: what is issue you are getting or error ? any html code for this ?

Comment: Apologies. HTML added

Comment: fix Jquery error and edit code.

Comment: Snippet still not working - need to rearrange CSS and add `<div id="counter"></div>`, and also add https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js as a script, so it starts to work (no images, though)

Comment: Have you tried changing it from `format: "dd:hh:mm:ss"` to `format: "mm:ss"` and from `startTime: "01:12:32:55"` to `startTime: "32:55"`?

Comment: Where did this mysterious `countdown.js` file come from?

Comment: You can download the png from here https://i.ibb.co/5hvG3DY/digits.png

Comment: Ive had this code lying about for a while but i want to reuse it but only displaying minutes and seconds

Comment: that doesnt seem to do anything. the days and hour sectiosn are still displayed

https://i.ibb.co/n8yj4cT/Screenshot-22.png

Answer (score 3):

Changing the startTime and format to use `mm:ss` format works for me.
If you need to just hide the digits while still having days and hours being counted down, you can just use style=`overflow:hidden; left: -50%`

```js
jQuery.fn.countdown = function(userOptions)
{
  // Default options
  var options = {
    stepTime: 60,
    // startTime and format MUST follow the same format.
    // also you cannot specify a format unordered (e.g. hh:ss:mm is wrong)
    format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
    startTime: "01:12:32:55",
    digitImages: 6,
    digitWidth: 53,
    digitHeight: 77,
    timerEnd: function(){},
    image: "digits.png"
  };
  var digits = [], interval;

  // Draw digits in given container
  var createDigits = function(where) 
  {
    var c = 0;
    // Iterate each startTime digit, if it is not a digit
    // we'll asume that it's a separator
    for (var i = 0; i < options.startTime.length; i++)
    {
      if (parseInt(options.startTime[i]) >= 0) 
      {
        elem = $('<div id="cnt_' + i + '" class="cntDigit" />').css({
          height: options.digitHeight * options.digitImages * 10, 
          float: 'left', background: 'url(\'' + options.image + '\')',
          width: options.digitWidth});
        digits.push(elem);
        margin(c, -((parseInt(options.startTime[i]) * options.digitHeight *
                              options.digitImages)));
        digits[c].__max = 9;
        // Add max digits, for example, first digit of minutes (mm) has 
        // a max of 5. Conditional max is used when the left digit has reach
        // the max. For example second "hours" digit has a conditional max of 4 
        switch (options.format[i]) {
          case 'h':
            digits[c].__max = (c % 2 == 0) ? 2: 9;
            if (c % 2 == 0)
              digits[c].__condmax = 4;
            break;
          case 'd': 
            digits[c].__max = 9;
            break;
          case 'm':
          case 's':
            digits[c].__max = (c % 2 == 0) ? 5: 9;
        }
        ++c;
      }
      else 
        elem = $('<div class="cntSeparator"/>').css({float: 'left'})
                .text(options.startTime[i]);

      where.append(elem)
    }
  };
  
  // Set or get element margin
  var margin = function(elem, val) 
  {
    if (val !== undefined)
      return digits[elem].css({'marginTop': val + 'px'});

    return parseInt(digits[elem].css('marginTop').replace('px', ''));
  };

  // Makes the movement. This is done by "digitImages" steps.
  var moveStep = function(elem) 
  {
    digits[elem]._digitInitial = -(digits[elem].__max * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages);
    return function _move() {
      mtop = margin(elem) + options.digitHeight;
      if (mtop == options.digitHeight) {
        margin(elem, digits[elem]._digitInitial);
        if (elem > 0) moveStep(elem - 1)();
        else 
        {
          clearInterval(interval);
          for (var i=0; i < digits.length; i++) margin(i, 0);
          options.timerEnd();
          return;
        }
        if ((elem > 0) && (digits[elem].__condmax !== undefined) && 
            (digits[elem - 1]._digitInitial == margin(elem - 1)))
          margin(elem, -(digits[elem].__condmax * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages));
        return;
      }

      margin(elem, mtop);
      if (margin(elem) / options.digitHeight % options.digitImages != 0)
        setTimeout(_move, options.stepTime);

      if (mtop == 0) digits[elem].__ismax = true;
    }
  };

  $.extend(options, userOptions);
  this.css({height: options.digitHeight, overflow: 'hidden'});
  createDigits(this);
  interval = setInterval(moveStep(digits.length - 1), 1000);
};
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Countdown that doesn't sucks</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#counter').countdown({
          image: 'https://i.ibb.co/5hvG3DY/digits.png',
          startTime: '05:00',
          format: "mm:ss"
        });

      });
    </script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
      br { clear: both; }
      .cntSeparator {
        font-size: 54px;
        margin: 10px 7px;
        color: #000;
      }
      .desc { margin: 7px 3px; }
      .desc div {
        float: left;
        font-family: Arial;
        width: 70px;
        margin-right: 65px;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="counter"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The countdown generates html inside the loop *`for (var i = 0; i < options.startTime.length; i++){}`* and it works on the basis of your init input ***startTime***, so in your case ***`"00:00:05:00"`***. instead of full length you just need to pass ***`"05:00"`*** will work for you.

Here the changed code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#counter').countdown({
      image: 'img/digits.png',
      startTime: '05:00'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the function that iterates over the time, because it depends on the length of the startTime parameter. In the createDigits function you can add the display: none style to hide the first 4 digits and separators:

```
   else 
    elem = $('<div class="cntSeparator"/>').css({float: 'left'})
            .text(options.startTime[i]);

   // ---- this hides the first 6 elements
    if (i < 6) {
      elem.css('display', 'none');
    }
  // -----
  where.append(elem)
```

This lets you specify the time with days and hours, but only show minutes and seconds.

On the other hand, if you just modify the startTime to "05:00" in the html, you can also have it work without touching the function, but I understand that you would like to have the full time specified.
This got it to work on my machine (after the adaptations from the comments).

Answer (score 0):

To display only hours and minutes use the correct starttime and format arguments

```
  $(function(){
    $('#counter').countdown({
      image: 'img/digits.png',
      format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
      startTime: '05:00'
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the momentjs package:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js
You can format time/data values like this:

```js
moment(time).format('/*Your format*/')
```

You can find how to format in the docs:
https://momentjs.com/